# printArea.js How to insert page breaks between div tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using printArea.js to print multiple div sections of a web page together.  Code is as follows:

```
$('div#key_retailer_overview,div#top_retailers,
div#key_retailer_by_upc,
div#key_retailer_by_store').printArea();
```

Problem is I can't get page breaks between the divs.  What is the markup to insert page breaks between each div?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

insert a class e.g. `<div class="page-break"></div>` on each of your divs

and then in your media queries

insert

```
@media all {
    .page-break { display: none; }
}

@media print {
    .page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
}
```

[Source](http://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks)